# How string isomorphism is used in graph isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Graph isomorphism is a special case of string isomorphism problem. In the paper of [Graph Isomorphism in Quasipolynomial Time](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03547),  the relation has been shown. Let,  two strings $x,y$ are associated with graphs $A, B$ (each has $n$ vertices) respectively. If there exists a permutation $\pi \in S_n$ (symmetric group of $n$ vertices), so that $x^{\pi}=y$,  it implies that $A^{\pi}=B$, i.e. graphs $A, B$ are isomorphic.

In the paper, the definition of string isomorphism is written on page 24 - $\newcommand{\Iso}{\operatorname{Iso}}\newcommand{\Aut}{\operatorname{Aut}}$

> Definition 3.2 (String Isomorphism Problem).
>
> Input: a set $\Omega$, a finite alphabet $\Sigma$, two strings
> $x, y :\Omega → \Sigma,$ a permutation group $G ≤ S(Ω)$ (given by a list of
> generators)
>
> Output: The set $\Iso_G(x, y)$. If this set is nonempty, it
> is represented by a list of generators of the group $\Aut_G(x)$ and
> a coset representative $\sigma \in \Iso_G(x, y)$.

here,  *$G$ is an arbitrary sub-group of $S(Ω)$* (see [this][2]). What  happens if  $\Iso_G(x, y)$ is empty?

If  $\Iso_G(x, y)$ is empty, then there might be $H > G$ where $\pi \in H$ and $\pi$ is an isomorphism. So,  $\Iso_G(x, y) = \emptyset$ does not imply $A, B$ are not isomorphic. In this case, what is the next step?

In general, why an arbitrary group $G$ is enough to check
graph isomorphism?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're somehow confused about which way the reduction goes and/or who gets choose $G$.

Someone who claims they have a solution to your "string isomorphism problem" *must be able to handle every possible subgroup we throw at them*. That's what it means to say that the group is arbitrary.

In particular if you're trying to solve the usual graph-isomorphism problem with the help of a string-isomorphism solver, having freedom to choose a group yourself *makes your job easier*. It means that you can construct a subgroup to represent exactly all of the possible permutation of the vertices in your graph, *and then the string-isomorphism solver has to work with the group you constructed*.

The group $G$ is part of the *input* to the string-isomorphism problem. Having a wide variety of possible inputs makes it (potentially) *more difficult* to find a general solution to the problem, but on the other hand makes it *easier* to *use* a solver as a tool for solving other problems.

So asking "why is an arbitrary group *enough* to check graph isomorphism" is fundamentally misunderstood. The more groups you have to choose between, the better the chance that the one you *need* in order to check a graph isomorphism. And when you get a free choice between *all of them*, as you do here, you can be *sure* that the group you need will be supported.

Comment: Do you mean every subgroup of $S_n$ when you write every posible subgroup? then if $ISO_G$  is  empty we take another group $H$ where $G <H$ and run the same routine/algorithm and keep doing it untill we find a non empty $ISO_G'$  set ?

Comment: @MikeSQ: Why would you do that? **As the user of the string-isomorphism solver, YOU get to choose dictatorially which group you ask it about**. If it answers that there is no isomorphism between the strings you have constructed form your graphs, using the group you have constructed from the graphs together with the strings, then you already know that the graphs are not isomorphic -- no need to do anything more. The string-isomorphism solver is not going to get its feelings hurt just because you don't keep running it until it can answer "yes" to something.

Comment: I have started  reading the paper in detail. I get the imprssion from your above comment that the $G$ is constructed ( 'using the group you have constructed from the graphs together with the strings' ),probably during some process. If you meant this, then see The Master Algorithm on page 74,  I see  no construction of $G$.  Can you tell me, how  $G$ is choosen/constructed ?If this is  not what you meant, then If  $Iso_G(x, y)$ is empty, there might be $H$ such that $G<H$ where $\pi \in H$ and $\pi$ is an isomorphism. So,  $Iso_G(x, y) = \emptyset$ does not imply $A, B$ are not isomorphic.

Comment: @MikeSQ: Do you mean page 78? What starts there is an _algorithm for solving the string-isomorphism problem_. It gets $G$ (as well as $x$ and $y$) as inputs. What I have been talking about is something else: a **reduction from graph-isomorphism to string-isomorphism**, which takes two graphs as input and produces $x$, $y$ and $G$ as output.

Comment: In other words, what I'm talking about -- and what I thought you were asking about -- is how the paper's Corollary 1.1.2 follows from Theorem 1.1.1. The paper does not seem to contain an explicit proof, perhaps because the author considered it trivial: Given two graphs both with k
nodes, let x and y be representations of their adjacency matrices, and let G be the group of permutations that permute the rows and columns of the adjacency matrices equally. Then this particular G contains a σ such that σ(x)=y exactly if the graphs are isomorphic.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am sorry  about the vagueness of my query. I know how GI is reduced into SI. My questions are - (1) how is group $G$ constructed ? (2) how  group $G$ is initiated in the algorithm .  Can you shed some light on that?  It appeared to me that the algorithm was  started with a subgroup of $S_n$, and it is choosen randomly.

Comment: @MikeSQ: I'm afraid I'm more confused than ever about what you're actually asking, then. As far as I can see, (1) $G$ is constructed as part of the reduction from GI to SI, which you say you already understand, and (2) $G$ is explicitly an _input_ to the master algorithm on page 78, so that's where it comes from. It says so right after the "Procedure String-Isomorphism" heading: $$\text{Input: group }G\le\mathfrak S(\Omega)\text{, strings }\mathfrak x,\mathfrak y: \Omega\to\Sigma $$ It is not clear to me why you think it would be chosen randomly.